# Extend computed properties in WCF Ria Services on client

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a business object that comes from a WCF service. I know that I can extend that business object by [creating a partial class on the client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707331%28v=vs.91%29.aspx). However, is it possible to extend a property that comes from the generated business object. For example, let's say that the business object has a property called Name. What I want to do is, **on the client**, to mark this property with the [DisplayAttribute].

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting the DisplayAttribute on the server-side class?

Comment: The DisplayAttribute is available only in Silverlight and .NET 4.0. My server is .net 3.5.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=vs.96%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Never used it for attributes, but I often use the pre-compiler statements to hide Silverlight/Client side code, when it compiles on the server.  For Example, this is often done to get to EntityState on both the server and client side:

```
#if SILVERLIGHT
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
#else
    using System.Data;
#endif
```

SILVERLIGHT is defined on the client side, but not on the Server side projects (conditional compilation symbol - project properties, Build tab).

I haven't tried it, but I'm thinking this might work with attributes?